# ¿Cómo crear la silueta de una imagen?

Tags: css, css3, filtros-css

Tengo diferentes imágenes en formato PNG que muestran objetos parecidos pero de diferente tamaño y que uso para superponerlas con una de forma semitransparente para comparar sus tamaños.

¿Es posible hacer que una imagen PNG se vea solo como una sombra/silueta negra usando CSS?

Por ejemplo, que una imagen como ésta:

[image]

Se vea así:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usando `jquery`:

```js
$("#newimg").css({
 WebkitFilter: 'grayscale(100%) brightness(0%)'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJ6Vs.png" id="originalimg" height="150px" width="auto" />
<br>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJ6Vs.png" id="newimg" height="150px" width="auto" />
```

Usando `css`:

```css
#newimg {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) brightness(0); /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
    filter: grayscale(100%) brightness(0);
}
```

```html
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJ6Vs.png" id="originalimg" height="150px" width="auto" />
    <br>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJ6Vs.png" id="newimg" height="150px" width="auto" />
```

Comment: Perfecto. Esa combinación de filtros me funciona genial. Muchas gracias